# iOS 7 rotated device not detecting landscape screen bounds

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, screen-orientation, detect

Was trying to change several labels and images width depend on the screen bounds after device gets rotated. Here's what I've tried:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] )) {

       CGSize newSize;

       newSize = CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

       NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(newSize));       

    }else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait( [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] )){

       CGSize newSize;

       newSize = CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

       NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(newSize));        
    }

}
```

It's supposed to log different width and height when I change the orientation

(like on [iphone5](/questions/tagged/iphone5) : {480,320} & {320,480})

works fine on [ios8](/questions/tagged/ios8),
but I got the same size results testing both on [ios7](/questions/tagged/ios7) simulator and [ios7](/questions/tagged/ios7) device.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Only from iOS8

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds
```

is interface-oriented (look at session "View Controller Advancements in iOS 8" of WWDC 2014), this means that in landscape mode on iOS8 height and width are reversed.

You can create an helper method like below to have the same behavior:

```
+(CGRect)getScreenBounds
{
    CGRect bounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
        bounds.size = CGSizeMake(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width);
    }
    return bounds;
}
```